# Proper way to evaluate policy + exploration offline in Vowlpal Wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

My use case is to retrain/make predictions using VW CB in batch mode (retrain/inference occurs nightly).

I'm reading [this](https://vowpalwabbit.org/tutorials/off_policy_evaluation.html#batch-scenario-policy-evaluation-with-a-pre-trained-vw-policy-cb_adf-format-data) tutorial for offline policy evaluation in the batch scenario. I'm training on a logged dataset using:

`--cb_adf --save_resume -f {MODEL_PATH} -d ./data/train.txt`

and in order to tune hyperparameter `epsilon` on batch predictions, I run the following commands 3 times on a separate dataset using:

`-i {MODEL_PATH} -t --cb_explore_adf --epsilon 0.1/0.2/0.3 -d ./data/eval.txt`

whichever gives the lowest average loss is the optimal epsilon.

Am I using the right options? My confusion mostly comes from the another option `--explore_eval`. What is the difference between `--explore_eval` and `cb_explore_adf` and what is the right way to evaluate model+exploration offline? Should I just run

`--explore_eval --epsilon 0.1/0.2/0.3 -d ./data/train+eval.txt`

and whichever gives the lowest average loss is the optimal epsilon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -i {MODEL_PATH} -t --cb_explore_adf --epsilon 0.1/0.2/0.3 -d ./data/eval.txt

I predict the result of this experiment: the optimal epsilon is the smallest.  This is because after data has been collected, there is no value to exploration.  In order to assess exploration, you have to change the data available at training in a manner sensitive to the exploration algorithm.  Which brings us to ...

> --explore_eval --epsilon 0.1/0.2/0.3 -d ./data/train+eval.txt

'--explore_eval' is designed to assess exploration. It requires more data to work well (since it discards the data if the exploration doesn't match) but allows you to assess exploration since it simulates the fog of war.

If you are testing other model hyperparameters such as base learning algorithm or interactions, the extra data overhead of '--explore_eval' is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Mineiro for the clarification! To summarize, is my understanding correct that: To tune model hyperparameters: 1. train on train.txt using --cb_adf 2. evaluate using --testonly without exploration on eval.txt and compare average losses; To tune exploration hyperparameters: 1. train on train.txt using --explore_eval 2. evaluate using --testonly without exploration on eval.txt and compare average losses.

Comment: I tagged the wrong name. Would you please see the comments above? @paul-mineiro

Comment: @HanaKaze: short answer is no.  

longer answer: your procedure will be misleading.  you are evaluating performance of the policy at the end of training interval.  in that case, you will find maximum exploration is best.  what you are missing is that exploration is expensive and you have to take into account the cost of acquiring data.

Comment: Thank you for the response again. My use case is a daily batch update of the model (as you mentioned,  performance of the policy at the end of training interval). Does this make sense? @paul-mineiro